# MongoDBManager: raw_query used for filtering

Tags: django, django-mongodb-engine

Is there a way to use raw_query to do additional filtering on a returned django.db.models.query.queryset.query? For example:

```
result = MyDocument.objects.raw_query({"foo.bar":{"$regex":"test.*", "$options":"i"}})
```

Then

```
result_1 = result.raw_query({"another.foo.bar":{"$regex":"test.*", "$options":"i"}})
```

I know this will not work, but is there a way to make this possible? Any recommendations?
I tried equating QuerySet to MongoDBManager() but it did not work as well.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: any ideas from anyone?

Comment: Any chance this question got an answer for you? I'm facing the same problem right now.